# NoReverseMatch at /app/detail/3/

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
NoReverseMatch at /app/detail/3/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/detail\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$'] .
```

I wrote in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    page = _get_page(blog_content, request.GET.get('page'))
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content,"page":page})

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = POST
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

in top.html

```
<div>
         {% for content in page %}
            <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
            <p><a href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

in detail.html

```
<div>

        <h2>Comment List</h2>

        <a href="{% url 'comment' pk %}">Comment</a>

        {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %} Name:{{ comment.name }}
        <br> Text:{{ comment.text }}
        <br>

        <a href="{% url 'recomment' comment.pk %}">Reply</a>
        <br> {% endfor %}

    </div>


    <div>

        <h2>Comment Form</h2>

        <form action="" method="POST">

            {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit">Send</button>

        </form>

    </div>
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(template_name='detail.html'), name='detail'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/',views.comment, name='comment'),
    path('recomment/<int:pk>/', views.recomment, name='recomment'),
]
```

When I access top.html, web site is shown correctly , so it is ok. But when I put SHOW DETAIL links, this error happens. I really cannot understand why this error happens.

Comment: show your `urls.py`.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I updated my question.

Comment: You shadow your context variable `'content'` in the loop `for content in page`. Then `content.pk` fails ...

Comment: @schwobaseggl No,when I access detail.html,this error happens.Not top.html.

Comment: @user7676799 At least from the snippets you are showing, you do not use the url `'detail'` in `detail.html`

Comment: @schwobaseggl I cannot catch ur messages.So,how should I fix this?

Comment: The error is coming from `/app/detail/3/`, which is handled by the `DetailView` which uses the `detail.html` template. However the template you have shown does not contain `{% url 'detail' ... %}` so would not give that error. We can't help you, because you haven't shown the code that is causing the error.